# How to get the human readable format of back stack entries? (Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to know which all fragments are in my back stack at a particular instance. So far what I have tried is this:

```
FragmentManager Fm = getFragmentManager(); 

        for (int i = 0; i< Fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++){
            System.out.println(Fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getBreadCrumbTitleRes());
        }
```

I also tried the `Fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).toString();` also the `.getId()` but that is not human readable. Though the above code gives me a zero or  a null, I still don't know which fragment is at what position. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try getName() method from BackStackEntry object?

Comment: There is no getName() method to the Fragment Manager class.
The method getName() is undefined for the type FragmentManager.BackStackEntry

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html#getName()

Comment: Yes I read that too, but its amazing how I am getting this error. I also set a tag to the fragment while starting its intent.

Comment: Okay I have it, it was introduced in API 14 while mine is only 11.

Comment: You should use support library instead then - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html#getName()

Comment: Noi I needed the name only for testing purpose. I had changed the API level while I needed that, reverted back to 11. :)